# vue js mutli vselect not allow for duplicate selection from dropdownlist

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good Day, I am new to vue.js, I would like for the values such as foo if it has been selected to be disabled when i try to select it again.The problem is when i select the second such as bar i can go back and select the first one which is foo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWBKB.png)
This is my code.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  selected:"",
    options: [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: 'bar'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'baz'
      },
    ],

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e5099;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#app {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
<!-- use the latest release -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>


<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select multiple v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed
>   `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>`
>   to`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>`.It works.Run the code so you know what i am talking about...

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  selected:"",
    options: [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: 'bar'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'baz'
      },
    ],

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e5099;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#app {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
<!-- use the latest release -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.4.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select multiple v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behaviour since you put multiple attribute there but the foo option can not be selected twice.

If you insist to remove the foo option after you select, you can do it via watch the model ('selected') and check if it's value is changed, then remove the foo from options. And also if you remove foo, then you can grab the previous value of the model ('selected'), compare it and put the deleted one to the options.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Hope this will help you :)